# What is the most popular Flash uploader?

Tags: flash, file-upload

To use it on a web page...

Comment: I used ajaxUpload function (because I didn't need to track progress).

Comment: It depends on what features you need.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) (its [Alexa Ranking](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/uploadify.com) is very high), but it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Well There Is Uploadify which is excellent
there is also a great called [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), from the guys who made TinyMCE.
Plupload can work with all major frameworks, not just flash.